# Printing a Dictionary with format

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm in need of printing a 2048 game board to the screen and i've designed a function for that, but it's not how my teacher asked me to do it.

my teacher wants me to do it like this

```
[ x ] [ x ] [ x ] [ x ]
[ x ] [ x ] [ x ] [ x ]
[ x ] [ x ] [ x ] [ x ]
[ x ] [ x ] [ x ] [ x ]
Score:
```

where x has the value in the board dictionary.

Problem is, I did this:

```
def tabuleiro_print(t):

    for c in range(1, 5):
            for i in range(1, 5):
                print '{:2d}'.format(t[i,c]),
            print
    print
```

where t is the board dictionary containing the coordinates and the value in this format:
{(1,1):value,(1,2):value2....and so on}

but my return is:

```
 2
16
 2
 0
 4
64
 4
 2
 2
32
16
 4
 8
 4
 8
 2
```

How can I go around this?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not get the output you claim, `tabuleiro_print({(x, y): 1 for x, y in product(range(1, 5), repeat=2)})` (after `from itertools import product`) prints a neat grid of `1`s.

Comment: Don't use Python2, it's not the future.

Comment: The two `print` lines are `SyntaxError` in Python3, are you sure you're not using Python2?

Comment: Forgot to type th () when posting, sorry

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a few other things, since your code works just fine with @jonrsharpe's example (I tested it too and it works). You can give us the input you tested your function with for example.

Answer (score -1):

```
def printIt(table):
    maxY, maxX = table.keys()[len(table) - 1]
    for i in range(1, maxY + 1):
        for j in range(1, maxX + 1):
            print '[%s]' % table[(i,j)],
        print
```

This should do the trick

EDIT : I don't know how to do it in Py3, this is only for 2.7

Comment: It didn't work, i Changed table for my variable and I got this:builtins.TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: This makes no sense. Dictionaries are *unordered*, so there's no guarantee that the "last" key will be the largest.

Comment: Well, i need to do it with the dict keys, which is why i use 2 for loops to go through my dict